# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.panResponder.panHandlers')

Tags: react-native

```
import ViewPager from 'react-native-viewpager'
_renderPage(data: Object, pageID: number | string) {
        return (
              <View style={{flex:1}} key={data.id}>
                    <Image {...this.panResponder.panHandlers} style={[this.state._circleStyles,{width:300,height:300}]} source={{uri : 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}/>
              </View>
        );
  }
render(){
<ViewPager
     ref={(viewpager) => {this.viewpager = viewpager}}
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     renderPage={this._renderPage}
     isLoop={false}
     renderPageIndicator={false}
     locked={true} autoPlay={false}/>
}
```

This code:

```
{...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
```

It works fine in render () function. But the _renderPage () function shows the following error message. How can this problem be corrected?

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.panResponder.panHandlers')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because _renderPage has a different scope and "this" wont work there as you expected. Solution is to bind the parent scope to that function.

Example Code:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._renderPage = this._renderPage.bind(this);
  }
}
```